# Method DocumentsContract.deleteDocument not delete file created from Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, file, uri, android-contentresolver, android-11

First, I call ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "example1.xls");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SAVE);
```

Then I try to delete file that user write in ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT dialog:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SAVE) {
            try {
                boolean del = DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                Log.d("myLogs", "del = " + del);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result file (that was created user with uri "data.getData()") is not deleted (I see it in file-manager) but method "deleteDocument" returns  true.
Help me please, what I do wrong? How can I delete file that was created user from ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT?
I need to delete this file so as not to clutter up the storage with unnecessary files (if the user created a file with the wrong name).

PS

1. I need that it's worked in 11 Android without permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
2. here (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) is written that you can delete the document if you have the URI for a document and the document's Document.COLUMN_FLAGS contains SUPPORTS_DELETE. But I don't understand how to set and check this flag.

Comment: data.getFlags() will get you the flags. But you can not set it. You can only look if it is set. Please tell value of data.getData().toString().

Comment: Anyhow it is a strange story. But deleteDocument was long not supported. Which Android version on used device?

Comment: data.getFlags() returns 67     
data.getData().toString() returns content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/648     
I test app on 11 Android.      
minSdkVersion - 19,  targetSdkVersion - 30 (11 Android).

Comment: 67 does not tell us very much. Every flag is a bit set. Inspect the flags/bits separately.

Comment: Try to create a file in a different directory. (Not the Download directory).

Comment: @blackapps 
I tried to create and delete file in Documents directory and it's WORK!!! Thank you very much for idea. But to be honest, this is strange because in both cases this code "(data.getFlags() & DocumentsContract.Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE) == 0" returns true. This means that in both cases I don't have permission for delete. May you know what does it mean?

Comment: @blackapps 
And may be you know how to set init directories for ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT? I tried  this code: 
"intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Uri.parse(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS))" 
but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Also inspect flag Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION. I think if you create in Documents directory you are working with a different content provider. Not `com.android.providers.downloads.documents`. Please tell full content scheme.

Comment: You should put as INITIAL_URI an uri you obtained before with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: `"(data.getFlags() & DocumentsContract.Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE) == 0"` Hmmm.. That would indicate that the flag is not set! It is only set if > 0.

Comment: I am very confused. My code remains the same, but now I can delete a file even in the download folder. Moreover code "(data.getFlags() & DocumentsContract.Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE) == 0" returns true too. It is very frustrating that it is not clear what the problem was and why it disappeared at the same device. Thank you very much for your help.